# Dynamic html elements to callback in require cache

Tags: dojo

I want to change/use/pass html element as dynamic based on user. How do I achieve.

I have used ajax request for getting and setting values to global variable before require cache. But its won't work because ajax take little time and require runs instantly.

```
        var ajaxReturn = "";

        $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8080/domain/_search?q=DomainId:15&from=0&size=100",
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (result) {

                    ajaxReturn = '<div data-dojo-attach-point="dropDownNode"></div>';
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log("Error....");
                }
        });


        require({
            cache: {
                "url:local/store/dropDown.html": ajaxReturn
            }
        });

        define("local/store/dropDown", "a, b, c, d, e, f".split(" "), function(a, b, c, d, e, f) {

            a = a(d, {templateString: e});

            return a
        });
```

I want to pass dynamic html elements to ajaxReturn in inside the require cache.

Answer (score 0):

For best user experience I you should rethink your code, first require anything, then make ajax calls.

But, one way to 'fix' this is to add `async: false` in your Ajax call. That makes the call synchronous so you public var will have a value.

Example:

```
   $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8080/domain/_search?q=DomainId:15&from=0&size=100",
            async:false,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (result) {

                ajaxReturn = '<div data-dojo-attach-point="dropDownNode"></div>';
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("Error....");
            }
    });
```

Comment: I have tried that way but not working what I was expected. But I did work around through skipping the require function(avoid using require cache).